# Xamarin.UITest: How To Pause a Test Step

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I have a UITest written in C#/Xamarin and the test is executing too quickly, causing it to fail. I need the test to wait for an Image to appear on the screen before executing the next step.

How can I pause the Xamarin UITest and make it wait for an Image to load on the screen before continuing to the next step?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my experience, there are a couple of ways to pause or slow down Xamarin.UITest.

## Best Way

Use the `WaitForElement` API.

For example, here I am waiting for a Button called "imageButton".

`app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("imageButton"));`

The example above waits for the element "imageButton" to appear before executing another step.

## Another Way

In the case you don't know what element you want to interact with or you simply want to pause Xamarin.UITest, you can use `Thread.Sleep`:

`Thread.Sleep(8000);`

Here, I'm pausing Xamarin.UITest for 8 seconds. It is important to note that you will need to add this library to use `Thread.Sleep`:

`using System.Threading;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` in `app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("imageButton");`

Comment: Thanks Kent! Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

## The problem with "pausing" UITest

You asked:

> "How can I pause the Xamarin.UITest and make it wait for an Image to load on the screen before continuing to the next step?"

It is *possible* to pause Xamarin.UITest using something like `Thread.Sleep()` for whatever length of time you require. However, the problem with this is that `Thread.Sleep ()` freezes the test run inflexibly. For example, if you set `Thread.Sleep (10000)`, then the thread would pause for exactly 10 seconds, regardless of how long your app actually takes to load the desired element.

If your picture only takes 1 second to load on faster devices, then using `Thread.Sleep(10000)` your test will still always take at *least* 10 seconds. What's worse is if you use this approach and don't `Thread.Sleep` long enough, the test will still fail; so you have to force your tests to run as slow as your "worst case scenario" every single time. More info: [`Thread.Sleep` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx)

## Solution by waiting for a UI element without "pausing" execution

`Xamarin.UITest` has the [IApp.WaitForElement](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.IApp.WaitForElement/p/System.Func%7BXamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery,Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery%7D/System.String/System.Nullable%7BSystem.TimeSpan%7D/System.Nullable%7BSystem.TimeSpan%7D/System.Nullable%7BSystem.TimeSpan%7D/) & [IApp.WaitForNoElement](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.UITest.IApp/M/WaitForNoElement/) APIs to handle these scenarios. These APIs are superior to `Thread.Sleep` because you can customize the condition at which it resumes beyond just waiting for a set amount of time.

### Example

This snippet example will wait 90 seconds for an element to appear that is either labeled or has an ID as "myButton."

```
    // Wait up to 90 seconds for myButton to appear             
    app.WaitForElement(c=>c.Marked("myButton"), "Could not find myButton", new TimeSpan(0,0,0,90,0));
```

If the element takes only 30 seconds to load, than in this example `app.WaitForElement` will continue after 30 seconds, it will only throw the error "Could not find myButton" if after waiting the full 90 seconds the element is still hasn't appeared.

### Simple query using default timeouts & error messages

You can also use either of these API calls without defining a timeout length, in which case for local UITests they will timeout after 15 seconds, or if run in Xamarin Test Cloud the will timeout after 1 minute. Source: [Xamarin.UITest "Timeouts & Waiting" guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/timeouts/)

This is the simplest possible form of the above query, using the default timeouts & default error message "Timed out waiting for element...":

```
    app.WaitForElement (x => x.Marked ("myButton"));
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution works if you aren't waiting for a particular UI element and don't want to sleep the current thread:

```
public static void WaitForTimeSpan(IApp app, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    try
    {
        app.WaitForElement(c => c.Text("BLAH BLAH BLAH"), "Waiting for something, killing time", timeSpan);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //do nothing we just wanted to kill some time
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, note however that there will be an error message in the output log regardless. The test will not fail though.